# My swamp cooler is leaving everything in the house black, why?

Tags: air-conditioning

It's a brand new swamp cooler. I've called the landlord twice to fix it he said the belt fell off the first time then the second time he said there's nothing is wrong. It's the same problem from before. I noticed it doesn't blow as hard as it did before. It's leaving everything black in the house the walls, stove, counters, and i just saw my white curtain black where the air goes through. I'll upload a picture of that. Any ideas what can be the problem? Nonsmoking household. [image: window with black soot on curtain and ledge][image]

Comment: Is there a filter somewhere?

Comment: could it be mold?

Comment: If the pulleys the belt run over are misaligned, the belt could be wearing.

Comment: @PhilG Should post as an answer...

Comment: Thanks ill suggest this when he comes to fix it.

Comment: Makes sense. I have a new belt and for first time in 10 yrs have black dust under vent

Answer (score 2):

It is my experience that the bolt pattern used to mount the motor in a swamp cooler can easily allow the motor axis to be set not parallel with the axis of the fan shaft. When not aligned parallel the pulley on the motor, even when appearing to be lined up nicely with the fan pulley, can end up rubbing excessively on the sides of the drive belt. This can create excessive amounts of black dust as a belt wears. It is even more interesting that a new belt can be more subject to getting chewed up like this than an older used belt that has developed a glaze on its surface.